# Excel formula that copies cell content while removing text

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that will copy A1 to B1 while removing "-text3" (the second dash and the text that follows it.  The "text-text-text" format is consistent in column A).  The text1, text2 and text3 each represent a variety in inconsistent strings.

```
A1:  text1-text2-text3
B1:  text1-text2 (-text3 has been removed by the formula)
```

Comment: Always the second or is it the last `-`?

Comment: always the second and also always the last.  There are two dashes in every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","}}}",2))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: The text1, text2 and text3 each represent a variety in inconsistent strings...  I'm not literally removing "-text3".

Comment: The data in column A could look like this:

dkelsc-xnvhv-scb
kvavm-sn-wnvis
dskvn-hdhd-kdng
cks-lshe-bixb

Comment: Then how do you know what to remove.  Please edit your original post with the rule to decide what to remove.

Comment: I added more info:  (the second dash and the text that follows it).   That's what I need to removed.

Comment: Brilliant, Scott!  That's exactly what I needed!  Thank you!

Comment: @Kenny J, Please mark the post as accepted. It shows that the question is solved and gives you and the person who answered some credit [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), Thank you :)!

Comment: @KennyJ please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.